# Do I need a lock for multithreaded access of size of list in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I have got a list shared by multiple threads. I am using a lock for adding or removing items from the list.

I have got another thread who only needs to get the length of the list, do I need to use a lock also for that thread?

My posed this question because for instance with files you can read from multiple threads without locks and you need them only when writing to them.

Additional details: I am using Python 3.6.4